# Unable to set delegate using IB for KASlideShow

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, delegates

I am using the [KASlideShow pod](https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow)  for Swift. It handles a UIImageView to enable creation of slideshows

I was looking at an [example project](https://github.com/rpowelll/LiveLine/blob/master/LiveLine/Controllers/SlideshowViewController.swift) to learn how to use it .Im also a beginner at Swift

So my idea is this:

1. Drag an Image View onto the View Controller.
2. Create an outlet from Image View by Ctrl+Drag the Image View object to the VC Swift file and create it of type KASlideShow! example:

   @IBOutlet weak var slideshowView: KASlideShow!
3. the class should reference the Protocol delegate example:

   class SlideshowViewController: UIViewController, KASlideShowDelegate
4. Set the delegate, but how?
   As I am unable to do this using the Ctrl+Drag mechanism, I just type out

   slideshowView.delegate = self

The above bombs with a stack output showing:

```
2015-11-17 12:10:22.681 Mimi[15268:1084006] -[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc7f2efb2d0
2015-11-17 12:10:22.698 Mimi[15268:1084006] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc7f2efb2d0'
```

I know Im missing a small and easy way out of this! Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the storyboard, are you setting the class on the ImageView there as well?  (not just the outlet)

[image: Change Class Here]

Comment: Looks like that's indeed the cause of the failure, since it's complaining about `[UIView setDelegate]` instead of `[KASlideShowView setDelegate`]. Also of note, you can set delegates in IB by dragging `delegate` to the desired view controller in the tree view.

Comment: I dont follow- should the custom class be set to KASlideShow? I tried that, it doesnt seem to get used (it reverts back to the greyed options)

Comment: Nevermind it works! turns out KASlideShow will appear as  a custom class for a View Object and not ImageView Objects - with that and the answer here my problem is solved!